# Cannot resolve dimen/detail_backdrop_height

Tags: android

I have managed to implement animations regarding the CoordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout and CollapsableToolBarLayout. The only issue is that as recommended on many tutorials, my AppBarLayout's height should be: `dimen/detail_backdrop_height` but that value is nowhere to be found in my.

Gradle:

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:design:$SUPPORT_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$SUPPORT_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$SUPPORT_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:percent:$SUPPORT_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:$SUPPORT_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:$SUPPORT_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:transition:$SUPPORT_VERSION"
```

$SUPPORT_VERSION = 25.0.1

Comment: you should define it by yourself in your dimens.xml

Comment: @AlexanderPerfilyev What should the value be? Considering I am trying to keep a recommended aspect ratio. At the moment I am just assigning it to 250dp. I have an ImageView inside the the toolbar. But 250dp doesn't seem like a good number. I'm not sure how to keep the aspect ratio.

Comment: it depends on the device. use this https://github.com/googlesamples/android-unsplash/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/unsplash/ui/ThreeTwoImageView.java to keep 3:2 aspect ratio for your image.

Comment: @AlexanderPerfilyev That won't fix the issue as the AppBarLayout will still be 250dp (or whatever).

Comment: just set layout_height to "wrap_content"